# Debugging nodejs run by babel-node with WebStorm

Tags: express, npm, webstorm

I have `npm run` script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon lib/app.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
}
```

How do you start a debugging session on WebStorm with this script?

Answer (score 5):

Right-click on **package.json** in the Project view and select **"Show npm Scripts"**:

[image]

This will display the **npm Tool Window** with a list of your scripts. Right-click on a script and select **Debug 'start'** (for example):

[image]

[NPM Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/npm-tool-window.html)

For the debugger to work (so that it stops at breakpoints, etc.) you need to add the string **$NODE_DEBUG_OPTION** to the script definition, for example:

```
"scripts": {
   blah: node $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION blah.js
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! I'm able to run the script that way but it doesn't stop at breakpoints. Is it the way Webstorm is supposed to work?

Comment: $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION didn't help me here either. It turned out that it is  babel-node issue.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the debug on WebStorm doesn't work with `babel-node` because `babel-node` does NOT output the transformed code. The issue tracker is [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17151)